# Does the python script have to be named as handler.py in AWS Lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, handler

Does the python script have to be named as handler.py in AWS Lambda?

I can't remember where I read this from, it says lambda is configured to look for a specific file, usually named 'handler.py',just wondering where we can configure this or does it have to be 'handler.py'? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can name this Python script whatever you want. Be sure to reference it properly.

> You can tell the Lambda runtime which handler method to invoke by setting the handler parameter on your function's configuration.

> When you configure a function in Python, the value of the handler setting is the file name and the name of the handler module, separated by a dot. For example, `main.Handler` calls the `Handler` method defined in `main.py`.

Comment: Can I ask a follow-up question please? Do I need to upload the dependencies (the libraries in the requirements.txt file) along with the script to Lambda?

Comment: yes, you need to package all your dependencies @Cecilia

Answer (score 2):

Nope it need not necessarily be named as handler.py.

you can name whatever you want but in lambda handler give as

> file_name.function_name

Just like a import

If you what have your handler file inside folders kindly include

> **init**.py

in all folders and perform a normal import like below

```
 src/
      __init__.py
      app.py
```

You can do import as src.app.function_name in handler config

Comment: Can I ask a follow-up question please? Do I need to upload the dependencies (the libraries in the requirements.txt file) along with the script to Lambda?

Comment: Better keep them in a lambda layer as it can be shared across lambda's and also helps for onscreen edit in lambda console

Answer (score 2):

> Does the python script have to be named as handler.py in AWS Lambda

Shortly No, you could specify any method which could process lambda event. (Usually combination is event + context (event, context)

> Just wondering where we can configure this or does it have to be
> 'handler.py'?

It really depends how you build and deploy your lambda but shortly handler property is telling you which method to be invoked and you could specify is as relative path to your deployment package - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-lambda-function.html#cfn-lambda-function-handler.

- template.yml

```
LambdaFunction:
  Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
  Properties:
    Handler: index.handler
```

- serverless framework
  In your serverless.yml file you need to define functions with handler https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/functions/
- aws cli
  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-package.html